# Hibernate annotation for lookup column

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three tables : po_dtl and workbook_types.
Each purchase order line (po_dtl) will have "workbook_code" column to refer to workbook_types.
Basically, po_dtl.workbook_code is only a lookup code to workbook_types.workbook_code.

The simplified java class are

```
@Entity
@Table(name="po_dtl")
public class PurchaseOrderDtl {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "po_dtl_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "po_dtl_s")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "po_dtl_s", sequenceName = "po_dtl_s", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "price_base", length = 7)
    private int priceBase;

    // ??? What is the annotation for workbook_Types?
    private WorkbookType workbookType;

    ....
}
```

While the workbook_types

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workbook_types")
public class WorkbookType {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "workbook_code")
    private String workbookCode;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 255)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "file_root_path", length = 255)
    private String fileRootPath;
    ....
}
```

What i ussualy use (without hibernate) is :

- workbook_types.workbook_code contains string "wbook_finance",
  "wbook_marketing"
- each po_dtl.workbook_code will contains "wbook_finance" or
  "wbook_marketing"
- workbook_types will only contains 2 rows with unique workbook_code, while po_dtl will contains many rows, but each row must contains only "wbook_finance" or "wbook_marketing"

Thanks

Comment: Try follow the instructions in that link--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704474/annotations-for-hibernate-lookup-table-type

Comment: Please review your question, it is impossible to understand what do you want =) U got 2 or 3 tables? order_detail or po_dtl?

Comment: @Vovka sorry, should be 2 tables : po_dtl and workbook_types

Comment: @rudiLadeon Thanks, but I think the link is not suitable. It may works for my WorkbookType class, but not for the PurchaseOrderDtl

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, you need @ManyToOne
Or use enum if new workbook_type's added only at developing stage.

```
@Entity
class Country  { //Country Dictionary

}

@Entity
class User {
    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
}
```

see [How to design tables for data dictionary when using hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822179/how-to-design-tables-for-data-dictionary-when-using-hibernate)